# Cannot ssh into Spark worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, ssh, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

There are 8 failed tasks in a particular executor. I want to connect to it via ssh to view the yarn logs.

The executor address is: `ip-123-45-6-78.us-west-2.compute.internal:34265`

I've tried both:

```
ssh ip-123-45-6-78.us-west-2.compute.internal:34265
```

and

```
ssh ip-123-45-6-78.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

But both produce the following error:

> Could not resolve hostname ip-123-45-6-78.us-west-2.compute.internal:
> Name or service not known

I've also added to the `.ssh/config` file the same key-pair I use to connect to the master:

```
Host master
        HostName ec2-09-876-543-21.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
        User hadoop
        IdentityFile ~/keypair.pem

Host worker
        HostName ip-123-45-6-78.us-west-2.compute.internal
        User hadoop
        IdentityFile ~/keypair.pem
```

And also both `ssh worker` and `ssh worker:34265` don't work.

Just to be clear: `ssh master` does work!

The Spark application is running on an EMR cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the hostname `*.compute.internal` these are internal IP address **(private IP)** and you can not `ssh` from your local system.

You are able to `SSH` to `master`  because you are using **public IP** address of the master instance. try to use the public IP address for the worker too and it should work.

Or the option is to create `ssh-tunnel` through the master server, you can try something like

```
Host worker
        HostName ip-123-45-6-78.us-west-2.compute.internal
        User hadoop
        IdentityFile ~/keypair.pem
        ProxyCommand ssh master -W %h:%p
```

Answer (score 0):

The hostname you're trying to connect to [will not resolve as you're outside of the AWS VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html). Private records (those as part of the `compute.internal` domain) only resolve if the DNS of the network goes through the Route 53 Private Resolver.

If you're not to worried about resolving the DNS hostnames you can instead attempt connecting via the private IP directly (assuming you have access via either a [VPN connection](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/) or [Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/)). Alternatively connect via an instance that has public ingress i.e. Client -> Jump Server -> Private Host.

If you do want to resolve via private domain name the following are the best options:

- [Inbound Resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-resolve-with-inbound-endpoint/)
- [Simple AD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_simple_ad.html)
- Setup an EC2 based DNS server in your VPC.